# Register Application programmatically for Graphic card

Tags: c#, graphics, installation, registry

I am trying to write a Setup for an application with Inno Setup, which is pretty neat by the way ;) , but now I am stuck with a problem regarding the graphiccard.

I am installing a 3D application and want to configure the program so that it uses a certain graphic card as default.
It sounded logical to me that somewhere in the registry must be a something to configure that.
I tried to change the default graphiccard manually und compare the changes in the registry but couldn't find any entrys relative to the changes

I know that programs like Adobe Photoshop are using the high performance graphiccards by default so there must be some kind of solution to my problem.

I am using inno script to write my setup but I can call external programs to do some tasks so I could write a C# program to execute this task.

This option is mostly relevant for Windows 7 and Windows 8 because I only saw it there.

Does anyone of you know how to change the default graphiccard of an application programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

Your approach, sorry, sucks. This is not something you should do during setup. What if the card changes?

Check it during application start. Let the user choose if you do not find anything. Let him update. Not everyone has only one graphics card. People do update the graphics card. Why should I rerun setup just to get this done?

And it is quite easy to identify graphics cards, performance is another story. Which one is "high performance" in your eyes?

Comment: If you have a newer pc or laptop with two graphiccards in it you can choose, by rightclicking the executable, the graphiccard that the application should use. i have an intel (low performance) and an nvidia (high performance) graphiccard, so i guess i could get things like vendor ID and memory to determine the better one and set it as default for the application, the user can change it afterwards anyway if he doesn't want it that way. The problem is that most users of the software complain about poor performance of the software but 99.9% of the time its just the wrong graphiccard

Comment: Make a Piece of Software that tries them out. Run it manually after first start, find out whih Card is faster. GENERALLY: Ignore Intel if something else is there (Intel is AWLAYS slow, it is the worst of them).

Comment: The problem is where do i register which card to use ? i can manually set a graphiccard for each program but i need to do it programatically.

Comment: Well, your program can select, or?

Comment: Nope, windows can. I do a rightclick on a program and click "Run with graphics processor" and this works with every program, but as i said i have to choose which one is the default.